# Setting up spring boot with lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I was trying to set up lombok in STS.

These are the steps I have done: I downloaded a lambok jar file and have specified my sts.exe path.
I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

After this, I closed my sts and also updated my project. My maven dependencies folder should have a lombok.jar file in it. But there is no such file. I have tried other links but in vain. Please help what step I am missing?

Edit: So I actually switched to visual studio code and in order to use lombok in vscode, you will have to install lombok extension.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-ide

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I have already done the steps mentioned here

Comment: Did you try using '@Getter' and '@Setter' ,if yes do they give error?

Answer (score 0):

check if your dependecy is inside a depencencies :

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

also you could check :

- https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven
- https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok

Comment: Yes, it is. I dont understand why my maven dependencies folder is not showing the lambok.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

then save and then run a Maven cmd, I would run something like `mvn clean install` this should download all your `jars`, depending on your OS all maven `jars` will be in `users`-> `current logged in user` .m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok

Comment: I have the lambok jar in my m2 repository

Comment: @Unknown `My maven dependencies folder should have a lombok.jar file in it. But there is no such file.` isn't your problem fixed now?